# Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] for Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working on a project for a class and I am getting The [$injector:nomod] error even after declaring a module.js file. I'm still new to angular, I still went and checked all the other questions that had the same problem as me but non of them answered/worked for my problem. Here is my code, please help.

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/nomod?p0=MenuAppX
at angular.min.js:7
at angular.min.js:26
at b (angular.min.js:25)
at Object.module (angular.min.js:26)
at categories.component.js:4
at categories.component.js:12

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/nomod?p0=MenuAppX
at angular.min.js:7
at angular.min.js:26
at b (angular.min.js:25)
at Object.module (angular.min.js:26)
at items.component.js:4
at items.component.js:12

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/nomod?p0=MenuAppX
at angular.min.js:7
at angular.min.js:26
at b (angular.min.js:25)
at Object.module (angular.min.js:26)
at routes.js:4
at routes.js:25


Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=MenuAppX&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.5%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DMenuAppX%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A76%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A408%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A439)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A182%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A290%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A251)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)
at angular.min.js:7
at angular.min.js:43
at p (angular.min.js:8)
at g (angular.min.js:42)
at gb (angular.min.js:46)
at c (angular.min.js:22)
at Uc (angular.min.js:22)
at xe (angular.min.js:21)
at angular.min.js:333
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:38)
```

Index

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="MenuAppX">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Menu App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Welcome to the Chinese Menu Website</h1>

<ui-view></ui-view>

<!-- Libraries -->
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modules -->
<script src="src/MenuApp/menuapp.module.js"></script>
<script src="src/MenuApp/data.module.js"></script>
<!-- 'menuapp' modules artifacts -->
<script src="src/MenuApp/menudata.service.js"></script>
<script src="src/MenuApp/categories.component.js"></script>
<script src="src/MenuApp/items.component.js"></script>
<!-- Routes -->
<script src="src/routes.js"></script>
```

menuapp module

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular.module('MenuAppX', ['data']);

});
```

data module

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('data', ['MenuDataService'])

});
```

menuapp service

```
(function () {
  'use strict'
  angular.module('MenuAppX')
  .service('MenuDataService', MenuDataService);

  MenuDataService.$inject = ['$http'];
  MenuDataService = function($http) {
    var service = this;
    // var categoryPromise = service.getAllCategory();
    // var itemPromise = service.getItemsForCategory();
    // get later

    service.getAllCategory = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var categoriesResult =  $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: ('https://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json'),
      });
      deferred.resolve(categoriesResult);
    }
    service.getItemsForCategory = function(categoryShortName) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var itemsResult =  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: (' https://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/menu_items.json?category='),
    params: {
      category: categoryShortName
    }
  });
  deferred.resolve(itemsResult);
}
  };

});
```

categories component

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('MenuAppX')
.component('categoriesX', {
  templateUrl: 'src/MenuApp/template/categories.template.html',
  bindings: {
    categoriesR: '<'
  }
});

})();
```

items component

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('MenuAppX')
.component('categoriesX', {
templateUrl: 'src/MenuApp/template/categories.template.html',
  bindings: {
    categoriesR: '<'
  }
});

})();
```

routes

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular.module('MenuAppX')
 .config(RoutesConfig);

  RoutesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
  function RoutesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

   $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'src/MenuApp/template/home.template.html'
   })
   .state('category', {
     url: '/menuCategory',
     templateUrl: 'src/MenuApp/template/categories.template.html'
   })
   .state('items', {
     url: '/menuItems',
     templateUrl: 'src/MenuApp/template/items.template.html'
   })
 }
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load **`data`** module first inorder to load the **`MenuAppX`** module because its a dependency, change your order of references as

```
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modules -->
<script src="src/MenuApp/data.module.js"></script>
<script src="src/MenuApp/menuapp.module.js"></script>
<!-- 'menuapp' modules artifacts -->
<script src="src/MenuApp/menudata.service.js"></script>
<script src="src/MenuApp/categories.component.js"></script>
<script src="src/MenuApp/items.component.js"></script>
<!-- Routes -->
<script src="src/routes.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to get rid of the errors. Any other things that could be wrong? Please help and thank you.

Comment: I figured out it was something else creating errors. Thanks for your help.